# Continuously access multiple .txt files to server side using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am creating a **web application in PHP** for a vehicle tracker device. In which device creates a .txt file with its IMEI number on server through FTP protocol. I am accessing that file using PHP. Text file contains live latitude and longitude of a device or say vehicle. as,

```
174830.000,A,2847.8984,N,07608.3931,E,0.00,208.96,190516,M
```

Here is the string format I am receiving.I have converted that string into LAT-LONG properly and now I can see live location of a vehicle.
My question is, this is for single text file but when we recive 1000's of files it will be difficult to access those files at the same time.

**How should I access thousands of text files at a same time. I have seen CRON job but it repeats itself only after 1 minute and I am receiving data after 2 seconds.Is there any other method where I can access mutliple files at the same time after an interval of 2 seconds?**

**My hosting OS is CentOS.**

Comment: I would not use files for this but instead have the trackers post to a database.

Comment: You may wish to investigate "directory watchers" (https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cent+OS+directory+watcher)

Comment: @jeroen but device is using FTP protocol to update file with LAT-LONG how should I directly add those into database using FTP...?

Comment: Can't they make POST requests instead? If you really need to go with ftp / files, I would have a cron-job move the lines from the files to the database. That way only one process (apart from ftp...) accesses the files and you can do the rest (searching / displaying / manipulating) using the database.

Comment: Why do you think accessing 1000s of files would be difficult???

Comment: I would assume anyone that can handle the bizarre debugging and PLC of PHP programming could write a 100 line java / c / c# app that deals with it. Check out the thing @Alex posted, or just write one yourself. It is not rocket science. Also, make sure you have a timestamp in that data row.